# String obfuscation using C++ standard ibrary

Tags: c++, encryption, std

I want to obfuscate some string data stored locally on iOS/Android device. Something similar to a high score in a game. My goal is to thwart only the laziest people, so encrypting the data really isn't necessary. **What does the C++ Standard Library provide that can help?**

I looked briefly at [cryptopp.com](http://www.cryptopp.com/) and [libtomcrypt](https://github.com/libtom/libtomcrypt) but I think they're overkill for what I want to achieve.

Comment: Do a [Caesar cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) you just need to modify each character by a fixed amount....

Comment: Monoalphabetic ciphers, like the Caesar/additive cipher suggested by jsantander, are both very simple and easily broken. To add a little to the challenge, you might consider an affine cipher or Vigenere cipher. These are all very quick to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the string to be "encrypted" is not terribly long, you can use a [XOR cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xor_encryption).

Generate a random string with the same length as your input string and xor your input with it to encrypt and decrypt.

```
void xor_strings (string& message, const string& key) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < message.size(); ++i)
        message[i] ^= key[i];
}
```

If you save both strings in your file, it will just contain two random strings.

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement you can use the string encryption offered by [antispy C/C++ Obfuscation Library for all platforms](https://www.antispy.xyz).